# Segmentation Fault with looping through std String by character

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, char

I'm trying to make a program that requires me to loop through a string character by character and do said stuff to it. Here's what I have now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
int loopThroughString(const string& hello);

int main(void){
    while (true) {
        cout << "String? " ;
        string s;            
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, s);
        if (s.length() == 0){
            break;
        } 
        int answer = loopThroughString(s);
        cout << answer << endl;
    } 
    cout << endl;
}

int loopThroughString(const string& hello){
    int answer;
    string str = hello;
    char ch;
    stack<int> s1;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <str.size(); i++){
        ch = str[i];
        cout << "character ch of hello is: " << ch << "\n";
        for(int j=0; j < 10; j++){
            if(ch == j)
                s1.push(ch);
        }
    }
    result = s1.top();
    return result;
}
```

I'm setting the string hello in the main of the program which proceeds to call loopThroughString.

The problem is that every time I run the program I get Segmentation fault (core dumped) error when it tries to set char ch equal to the last character of the string. Can anyone help me understand why I am getting this error? I've tried everything!

EDIT: Updated to be more specific about what the program is doing!

Comment: It looks fine to me.  Are you sure this code is the cause of the problem?  Does the omitted code modify `str`?

Comment: Using `std::string` and `std::cout` works just fine. Check your includes and namespaces. Where is `String` defined for you?

Comment: Is your `String` a typedef of `std::string`? If not, your error may be there. What's happening in the constructor of `String`?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't supposed to be String, it was just str::string. I added some cout to my for loop for testing and if for example the string: "1+1" was entered, the for loop would run 2 times but give me the error on the third run when trying to set char ch = str[i].

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that it is undefined behaviour to call `s1.top()` on an empty stack. You should check for `! s1.empty()` before calling `s1.top()`.

The stack is usually empty because of the code:

```
for(int j=0; j < 10; j++){
     if(ch == j)
            s1.push(ch);
}
```

The character `ch` holds a character code; the character `'0'` has a different code to the integer `0`, etc.  A simple fix for this would be `for (char j = '0'; j <= '9'; ++j)`.

However you could replace that whole loop; for example `if ( std::isdigit(ch) ) s1.push(ch);`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the top of an empty stack.

Change

```
result = s1.top();
return result;
```

to

```
if ( s1.empty() )
{
   return -1;
}
else
{
   return s1.top();
}
```